# Can the Rav enforce his own made-up rule as a "penalty"?

Tags: halacha, rabbis

Several years ago, while making a trip to the Catskill area, I stopped near the large shul in Woodbridge, NY (I forgot its name). The rabbi has a reserved parking spot across the street from the shul.

The sign in front of the spot says:

"Reserved for the rabbi. Violators will have to deliver the sermon on Shabbat."

I must admit, it is a memorable humorous sign. I love it. But, I'm curious. Could the rabbi halachically impose his own made up "penalty"?

Offhand, I think he was being funny, but, let's say he really wanted to teach the violator a lesson that he shouldn't park there again. Is the rav allowed to impose any penalty he wishes for the purposes of "teaching a lesson"?

Comment: Of course he was being funny. If you want the Rabbi's privileges, you get his work too.

Comment: Seems like if you park in that spot, you are voluntarily entering into a contract which requires you to give the Shabbos sermon.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Daniel I assume that you were being humorous. U can't enter a contract for violating someone's property.

Comment: @yEz People occasionally downvote when either they don't have a sense of humor themselves, or don't think that I'm (not) trying to be "funny". Both funny-haha & funny-strange :-%

Comment: @Yishai If I get his work, I get his headaches, too. I don't want his Shabbat headache, b/c I can't take aspirin for it. Let the rav keep his own headache, and I'll just park across the street.

Comment: Who said the Rabbi enforces this, perhaps it is enforced by the local police force?

Comment: @GershonGold the local police force will make him say the derasha? :)

Comment: @GershonGold I think the rav IS the local police! ;-)

Comment: Sounds like a real hick town